# Is there an text editor/IDE with EBNF/BNF support?

Tags: ide, text-editor, bnf, ebnf

I will be writing a small grammar to parse a text file, the grammar can be a bit large so I want to read it with highlight.

<sub>*I know it's a bit off-question but find this using google is very hard. What else place is better than ask to this to a lot of experient programmers.*</sub>

Comment: Another alternative is ANTLR works: http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of.  There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1804038/3438854) for Emacs.  Apple [hosts](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/vim/vim-44/runtime/syntax/yacc.vim) a yacc syntax file for vim.  Based on what's mentioned [for this archive](http://johnmacfarlane.net/highlighting-kate/), [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) may also handle yacc, but I can't find a specific confirmation.

And yes, I'm mixing straight BNF with yacc.  The pickings were slim enough that it seems like a reasonable leap, and it might not be too hard to hack the yacc-specific parts out of the syntax descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

For BNF you could use IntelliJ from JetBrains with Grammar-Kit plugin.
EBNF support seems not included at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one: https://github.com/rochus-keller/EbnfStudio/blob/master/README.md.

It supports syntax highlighting, inline warnings, symbol navigation and cross-referencing. The grammar is automatically analyzed for syntax errors, missing non-terminals and left recursion while editing. The grammar can also be checked for LL(1) ambiguities and the effectiveness of conflict resolvers.